# What would cause a transition not to fire on a selected element

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a floating tooltip, with a text element that tracks the mouse position.  In the sample code, I attach an svg element to the document and add a mouseover event.  Afterwards, I attach a text element.

In the mouseover event, I select the text element by ID and attempt to move it by transition.  The mouseover event is triggering, but the transition is not firing.  I'm clearly missing something, but can't figure out what it might be.  Thanks in advance.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Create Event Handlers for mouse
        function handleMouseOver(d, i) {  // Add interactivity

        d3.select("#tooltipL1 text").transition()
            .attr('stroke', 'red')
            .attr("x", d3.event.pageX + 20)
            .attr("y", d3.event.pageY - 30);

        }

       var svgContainer = d3.select("#content")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 200);

        var tooltip = svgContainer
            .append("text")
            .attr("id", "tooltipL1")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
            .style("font-size", 14)
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .text("Row1");
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

I've tried most of the mobstock examples.  I thought that the lack of data or a g element might be playing a role and tried to add them, but to no avail.  but other examples don't seem to use them.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the tooltip incorrectly. In order to select the tooltip just use the id of the tooltip like below.

```
// Create Event Handlers for mouse
function handleMouseOver(d, i) {  // Add interactivity

d3.select("#tooltipL1").transition()
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr("x", d3.event.pageX + 20)
    .attr("y", d3.event.pageY - 30);

}
```

Also you may want to use mousemove instead of mouseover. The mouseover event terminates and may be more jittery. The mousemove event will follow the mouse.

So the code for the svg would be:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#content")
     .append("svg:svg")
     .attr("width", 200)
     .attr("height", 200)
     .on("mousemove", handleMouseOver);
```

This should work. Here is a working block: https://blockbuilder.org/akulmehta/5419f3cc86599b391578a54352eb107e